# Problems trying to find the XPath of the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[image]

I'm having problems using Selenium to automate some tasks. After using an XPath to search for the desired element, I try to click the button but it doesn't work. I was quite frustrated with this situation as I already tried several solutions but none of them solved the problem. I would like to find a way to resolve this issue as I need this automation to work properly to continue my projects.

I tried by ID, NAME and nothing worked.

This is the line I'm trying to run:

```
element = navegador.find_element(by='xpath', value='/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[9]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/input')
element.click()
```

This is the error that appears:

```
InvalidArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1752\1909305288.py in <module>
 39 time.sleep(5)
 40 element = navegador.find_element(by='xpath', value='/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[9]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/input')
---> 41 element.click()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the screenshot is showing us. It doesn't look related to the question. A screenshot of the UI of the page is fine but screenshots of code or HTML is not useful and should be removed. Please edit your question and add the relevant HTML for the element you are trying to click. Also, always add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: to debug this we need to see the DOM of the page, pls share the URL you are accessing or HTML of that page.